# Another word for sample

Tags: synonyms, slang

What is another word that is similar to or even has the same meaning as "sample", as in the little pieces of food that get handed out?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: Please also tell us why *sample* doesn’t work for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

They're often called a **taste**.

M-W defines it as [a small amount tasted.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/taste)

Comment: +1. In Britain they are usually caller ***tasters***. (Not to be confused with "one who tastes").